# Flutter: Image color does not match them color

Tags: ios, flutter

I a'm showing an image in flutter, which has a background color of 0xFF239b85. Below I have a card with the same background color. But when rendered in iOS, these colors are not the same.

I have even taken a screenshot and used color picker, and it comes out as two different colors:[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: It is hard to answer a question without the question's relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it myself. Turns out I used primary color from the theme, which was generated like this:

```
ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Color(0xFF239B85)
```

This will for some reason *not* make 0xFF239B85 into the primary color. I guess it is to light for the seed method to accept as primary.